# how to fetch every nth object using core data

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data

I have entity `Question`. Entity `Question` has property `Number`. I need to fetch every 20th question: 1, 21, 41, 61, etc. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an `NSFetchRequest` as usual, as well as an `NSPredicate` instance that uses a modulus operator, e.g. the following untested predicate:

```
NSPredicate *idPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"modulus:by:(Number, 20) == 1"];
```

Add the predicate to the fetch request, and do the fetch, as usual.

Or create an `NSSet` of ID values that include `{1, 21, 41, ...}` and use that with the predicate:

```
NSSet *idSet = /* set of NSNumber instances including 1, 21, etc. */
NSPredicate *idPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Number IN %@", idSet];
```

I haven't tested this, but either approach should get you close, I think.

Comment: I believe this is a great answer, Alex! How would it I need to change the predicate (modulus operator) to fetch every n th day? Instead of numbers, I have DateTime attributes in my data mode, each one represents one day (of a share price).

Comment: @AlexR Did you find a way to fetch every nth day?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to create a search mask with **NSPredicate** for the last digit. If you have less than 1,000,000 questions, I would fetch all questions and filter the numbers, schematically: `BOOL keepNumber = ((record.Number % 20) == 1)`. In general, iPad/iPhone RAM/CPU GHz/Core Data smarts are going up and the performance cost of a simple GET is unlikely to be important, especially compared to a more complicated GET, because the search predicate in Core Data would still have to examine every record.