# how to write predicate to retrieve only entities which have even property in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, predicate

I am working on a e-book reader application.I am using core data for storing information if user bookmarks a page.The core data entity for book mark object have several properties like page number,bookmark text etc.My requirement is to fetch all bookmarks for odd number pages in the entire book.The "page number" property of book mark entity is of "Integer 32" type in core data model.The following predicate is not working to fetch odd page bookmarks:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(bookPath == %@) AND (bookmarkPageIndex%2!=0)", self.bookPath];
```

where "bookmarkPageIndex" is bookmarked page number.

Please help how to test wether **bookmarkPageIndex** is even or odd while fetching from coredata.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651104/how-to-fetch-every-nth-object-using-core-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should use the escape operator for the `%` sign, which is `%%`.

Hopefully, `(bookmarkPageIndex%%2!=0)` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your predicate is missing the AND keyword between the two conditions.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(bookPath == %@)  AND (bookmarkPageIndex%2!=0)", self.bookPath];
```

Comment: sorry,that was written accidentally.I edited the question ,there was AND operator in my expression.does "%" operator work in predicates?